# Store filtered output of cmd command in a variable

Tags: python, variables, cmd

I am trying to store the output of a cmd command as a variable in python. 
To achieve  this i am using `os.system()` but `os.system()` just runs the process,it doesn't capture the output.

```
import os


PlatformName = os.system("adb shell getprop | grep -e 'bt.name'")
DeviceName = os.system("adb shell getprop | grep -e '.product.brand'")
DeviceID = os.system("adb shell getprop | grep -e 'serialno'")
Version = os.system("adb shell getprop | grep -e 'version.release'")

print(PlatformName)
print(DeviceName)
print(DeviceID)
print(Version)
```

Then i tried to use the `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess
import os


PlatformName = subprocess.check_output(["adb shell getprop | grep -e 'bt.name'"])
DeviceName = subprocess.check_output(["adb shell getprop | grep -e '.product.brand'"])
DeviceID = subprocess.check_output(["adb shell getprop | grep -e 'serialno'"])
Version = subprocess.check_output(["adb shell getprop | grep -e 'version.release'"])

print(PlatformName)
print(DeviceName)
print(DeviceID)
print(Version)
```

I am getting the following error

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified

How can I store the output of the command as a variable?

Comment: I think you should just separate each piece of your batch command with a comma.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output) for more info.

Comment: I think you should "native" grep from python... the issue is missing `shell=True`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have added `shell=True` and i got `CompletedProcess(args=["adb, shell getprop | grep -e 'bt.name'"], returncode=1)` but it still does not store the output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issues here:

- passing arguments like this (string in a list, with spaces) is really not recommended
- passing arguments like this need `shell=True` for it to have a slight chance to work, and `shell=True` is known for security issues (and other issues as well, like non-portability)
- `grep` is not standard on windows, and the pattern is a regex which means you'd probably have to escape `.` (`"bt\.name"`).
- when not found `grep` returns 1 and would make `check_output` fail.
- when found `grep` returns match(es), and a newline, that you'd have to strip

I'd rewrite this:

```
PlatformName = subprocess.check_output(["adb shell getprop | grep -e 'bt.name'"])
```

as:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["adb","shell","getprop"])
platform_name = next((line for line in output.decode().splitlines() if "bt.name" in line),"")
```

The second line is a "native" version of grep (without regexes). It returns the first occurrence of "bt.line" in the output lines or empty string if not found.

You don't need `grep` here (the above is not strictly equivalent, as it yields the *first* occurrence, not *all* the occurrences but that should be okay on your case). And your clients may not have `grep` installed on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i tried to run your code but I am getting an AttributeError: `'list' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: sorry, inverted both calls. Can you retry?

Comment: Working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I got the same problem as you. Sub-process can do what you want even with the `shell=False`. The trick is the [communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method.

```
with subprocess.Popen(cmdCode,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            cwd = workingDir,
                            bufsize=1,
                            universal_newlines = True) as proc:
    #output is stored in proc.stdout
    #errors are stored in proc.stderr
```

Now you just need a little function to scan the `proc.stdout` for the information you need: `PlatformName`, etc